# Visual Studio 2010 - Can't open O/R Designer

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

I just got Visual Studio 2010 and need to create a web application using LINQ to SQL.  I started writing the web app but can't add a .DBML file to the solution.  The option isn't there when I go to Add -> New Item.

Am I missing something from the installation CD?  Did they change something from Visual Studio 2008?  I haven't written in .NET for about a year, so I'm out of the loop.

Thanks very much for any help.